# Use a duplex (Bidirectional) delegate in Objective C

Tags: ios, delegates

I have 2 classes in Objective C.

Class A : ViewController
Class B : UITableViewController

In Storyboard, I add a Class B Object, and is called using a callback from Class A. I solved this problem using a Delegate in Class A.h:

```
#import "ClassB"

@interface ClassA : ViewController
< ClassBDelegate >
{ 
id<ClassADelegate> _delegateClassA;
}
```

In Class A.m:

```
@implementation ClassA

@synthesize delegateClassB = _delegateClassB;

@end
```

In Class B.h

```
@protocol ClassBDelegate

- (void)helloWorld

@end

@interface ClassB : UITableViewController
{
id<ClassBDelegate> _delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) id<ClassBDelegate> delegate;
}
```

In Class B.m i can use delegate correctly:

```
[_delegate helloWorld];
```

The problem is, I want also use the reverse way, a delegate from A to B class. I can´t use the same way to solve the problem in the other way because if I use import between B and A it make a circular import and I can´t compile the code.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need a delegate when class A already knows class B? You can simply store the reference and call a method that you previously defined in class A .h directly

Comment: @Ismael because it not the right way to do things like this. It will work but it is very bad approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make a delegate from your class A to B and B to A both. This is because to make a delegate you need to import the other class, and set the delegate to the other class.

I solved this problem using a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

With a Singleton, you can make usual delegates from External classes to the main one (A), as usual. Implementing the singleton as a static interface, can use the shared pointer from the Main class (A) to call functions callback in Singleton, and use delegates from singleton to B.

Using this method you will broke the circular header problem. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all protocols in one file, independent from viewControllers. Example Protocols.h/m and import this file without problems.

Comment: Implement another protocol give me the same problem, there are a imports in a circle and it doesn´t work. Thats because imports, its possible to define a delegate without include the class t ocompile it? something like declarate class to compile in c++ and link later.

Comment: My idea is to add all protocols in only one class, then you will be importing only this Protocls class, and you should avoid problem with imports circle?

Comment: But we can not call the protocol in two directions, its only available in one direction. If we try it, there are errors with the includes, circle includes error

Comment: I don't see hoy to make the protocol class in both ways. I improve that idea applying a singleton interface.